# GCP Bigquery Pagination Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have create a custom APIs for getting data from GCP BigQuery. My application is running on Cloud Run and API Gateway is used. How do apply a pagination for API. I do "POST" request on that URL
https://xxxxxxxxxx/data?start=20210101&end=20210731
Code Sample is like:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
query_res = client.query(query)
query_res.result()
destination = query_res.destination
rows = client.list_rows(destination, max_results=10000, page_size=10000)
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Its gives me first 10000 records only. How do I get the record for next page/all pages?

Comment: You need the page token also.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes, From where I suppose to get page token.

Comment: Do you want to perform a new request to get the next 10000 elements? Do you expect the page_token in your url? something like `&nextpage=<token>`?

Comment: Yes I want to get next 10000 element. Yes token in request header. How do I get token for next page? I am using POSTMAN to send request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use serverless, you can't keep in memory the data result, you need to perform again the query to BigQuery.

BUT, because it's the exact same query, you will reuse the case and therefore, the result will be instant and free.

I recommend you to use the `start_index` parameter

```
 rows = client.list_rows(destination, start_index=10000, page_size=10000)
```

Provide the start index in your query parameter, or the page number (a multiple of the page size).

*Note that your max result is useless, the page size is enough*

Comment: Thanks, it's help. I used 'start_index' and 'max_results'.